# How to iterate over a dictionary - n key-value pairs at a time

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large dictionary with thousands of elements. I need to execute a function with this dictionary as parameter. Now, instead of passing the whole dictionary in a single execution, I want to execute the function in batches - with x key-value pairs of the dictionary at a time.

I am doing the following:

```
mydict = ##some large hash
x = ##batch size
def some_func(data):
    ##do something on data
temp = {}
for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
        if len(temp) != 0 and len(temp)%x == 0:
                some_func(temp)
                temp = {}
                temp[key] = value
        else:
                temp[key] = value
if temp != {}:
        some_func(temp)
```

This looks very hackish to me. I want to know if there is an elegant/better way of doing this.

Comment: You could try [this (sub-dict from dict)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207481/1639625) or [this (split generator)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/1639625)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I often use this little utility:

```
import itertools

def chunked(it, size):
    it = iter(it)
    while True:
        p = tuple(itertools.islice(it, size))
        if not p:
            break
        yield p
```

For your use case:

```
for chunk in chunked(big_dict.iteritems(), batch_size):
    func(chunk)
```

Comment: Hi georg. Thanks for your answer. Please can you explain the performance of `chunked` method. Does is work better than the solution I have shared?

Comment: @nish: I guess it should be efficient. `itertools`  are written in C and are much faster than python.

Comment: In Python3 it will be `big_dict.items() instead of big_dict.iteritems()`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions adapted from earlier answers of mine.

Either, you can just get the list of `items` from the dictionary and create new `dict`s from slices of that list. This is not optimal, though, as it does a lot of copying of that huge dictionary.

```
def chunks(dictionary, size):
    items = dictionary.items()
    return (dict(items[i:i+size]) for i in range(0, len(items), size))
```

Alternatively, you can use some of the `itertools` module's functions to yield (generate) new sub-dictionaries as you loop. This is similar to @georg's answer, just using a `for` loop.

```
from itertools import chain, islice
def chunks(dictionary, size):
    iterator = dictionary.iteritems()
    for first in iterator:
        yield dict(chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1)))
```

Example usage. for both cases:

```
mydict = {i+1: chr(i+65) for i in range(26)}
for sub_d in chunks2(mydict, 10):
    some_func(sub_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [more-itertools](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py):

```
def chunked(iterable, n):
    """Break an iterable into lists of a given length::
        >>> list(chunked([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3))
        [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
    If the length of ``iterable`` is not evenly divisible by ``n``, the last
    returned list will be shorter.
    This is useful for splitting up a computation on a large number of keys
    into batches, to be pickled and sent off to worker processes. One example
    is operations on rows in MySQL, which does not implement server-side
    cursors properly and would otherwise load the entire dataset into RAM on
    the client.
    """
    # Doesn't seem to run into any number-of-args limits.
    for group in (list(g) for g in izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)] * n,
                                                fillvalue=_marker)):
        if group[-1] is _marker:
            # If this is the last group, shuck off the padding:
            del group[group.index(_marker):]
        yield group
```